# what difference between nltk tokenizer and RobertaTokenizer?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

why here we take `RobertaTokenizer` and why do we perform Word2Vec?

```py
 def __init__(self, modelpath, tokenizer):
        self.model = Word2Vec.load(modelpath)
        self.tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('microsoft/graphcodebert-base', cache_dir = config["cached_dir"])
```

what difference between NLTK tokenizer and `RobertaTokenizer`?
why we need `RobertaTokenizer` instead NLTK?
I know the NLTK tokenizer creates a word index of every word in the set and we perform word2vec to get the semantic meaning between words, but I a can not find why `RobertaTokenizer` is proposed instead tokenizer from NLTK?

Answer (score 0):

This question can be answered using a more abstract view. I can rephrase the question like this "when we already have word vectors for every single token, What makes us use Transformers architecture?" the answer,  let's assume you have the word **'bank'** in `I paid the money straight into my bank` and **'bank'** in `willows lined the bank`. As you may notice the word doesn't have the same meaning and the model should consider the difference. But with a single word vector assigned to the token, it's simply impossible. So there's a need for a model capable of modeling the difference and it is the exact thing that `BERT`, `RoBERTa`, `DistillBERT`, and any other Transformer-based model do!

**Update**

There are several ways of quantifying or vectorizing text pieces each having its own pros and cons. In some cases, they can be used alongside each other but generally, they are interchangeable and used individually.

- Bag of Words (simple but ineffective because doesn't care about word similarities)
- TF-IDF (simple yet efficient and better than BoW, doesn't consider word similarities)
- Word Dense Vectors (efficient, convenient, can't model different senses for a token in different contexts)
- Transformers family is known as WordPiece tokenizers (best way till now in terms of efficiency, relatively complex, and high computation consumption)

Comment: thank you for answering, you mean if I want to use word2vec after tokenizing, I should use RoBerta tokenizer because it differentiates between the meaning of word,  Question: if I donot want to use word2vec for example I want to use tf-idf model should I use RoBerta tokenizer or tokenizer from nltk

Comment: could please answer my question: why some time I see code like in my main question where they use RobertaTokenizer and they use word2vec model to convert word to vector (here the case study applying those on source code not text) @meti

Comment: I mean I see somtime they use tokenizer from nltk then word2vec, but another time I see they RobertaTokenizer and then word2vec, my question what is different between using nltk tokenizer and RobertaTokenizer then apply word2vec? Do you mean we should use RobertaTokenizer instead word2vec? or RobertaTokenizer is basic step before applying word2vec? please explain that I am so confused.

Comment: Honestly, I've never seen using `NLTK` along with `RoBERTa's tokenizer` - if you have, please share the link -  but using NLTK for separating and identifying tokens, then mapping identified tokens into semantic space using `word2vec` vectors is a well-known and popular method.  But keep in mind `RoBERTa's tokenizer` splits sentences into subwords that essentially are absent in `word2vec's vocabulary`.

Comment: Did the answer provide you with any help?